# How to put a multiline newline - delimit json which I am trying to put in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have this [ndjson file](https://gist.github.com/rfmcnally/0a5a16e09374da7dd478ffbe6ba52503) from a yelp API. I am trying to put it into a pandas dataframe. Eachline has a nested json.

How do I put it into a pandas dataframe? this is what I have so far

`

```
bn=pd.DataFrame(df.result.values.tolist())['extractorData']

sj = pd.json_normalize(bn)
```

`

I tried to itrate through explode but unfornately I need to store each line in a dataframe and then merge?

it came out like this clegane:

```
                                                     url      timestamp  \
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286383006   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286384917   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286395948   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286386420   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...  1513286387763   

   sequenceNumber  statusCode  pageData_timestamp  \
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
0               0         200       1513286383006   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
1               1         200       1513286384917   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
2               2         200       1513286395948   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
3               3         200       1513286386420   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   
4               4         200       1513286387763   

                                   extractorData_url  \
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts...   

                                                href  \
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/milk-and-wood-san-jos...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/dzuis-cakes-and-desse...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/recess-italian-ice-an...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/icicles-san-jose-7?os...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-rendezvous-san-...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/passion-t-snacks-and-...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/vampire-penguin-featu...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-gelato-tea-loun...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/matcha-love-san-jose-...   
0  https://www.yelp.com/biz/anton-sv-p%C3%A2tisse...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/oooh-san-jose-4?osq=D...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/hannah-san-jose?osq=D...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/chocatoo-san-jose?osq...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/nox-cookie-bar-san-jo...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-fix-creamery-sa...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/my-milkshake-san-jose...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/matcha-love-san-jose-...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/banana-cr%C3%AApe-san...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/marco-polo-italian-ic...   
1  https://www.yelp.com/biz/blackball-desserts-sa...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/anton-sv-p%C3%A2tisse...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/soyful-desserts-san-j...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/cocola-bakery-san-jos...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/charlies-cheesecake-w...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/jt-express-san-jose-2...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/nox-cookie-bar-san-jo...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/shuei-do-manju-shop-s...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/churros-el-guero-san-...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/sno-crave-tea-house-s...   
2  https://www.yelp.com/biz/j-sweets-san-jose-3?o...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/treatbot-san-jose-2?o...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/cream-san-jose?osq=De...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/my-milkshake-san-jose...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/peters-bakery-san-jos...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-charming-kitchen-...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-fix-creamery-sa...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/california-mochi-sant...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/raw-sugar-milpitas-2?...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/chola-desserts-san-jo...   
3  https://www.yelp.com/biz/san-jose-tofu-company...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-sweet-corner-san-...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/marco-polo-italian-ic...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/honeyberry-san-jose-9...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/my-ch%C3%A8-san-jose?...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/creme-paris-san-jose-...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/snowflake-san-jose?os...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/willow-glen-creamery-...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/vans-bakery-san-jose?...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/happiness-cafe-san-jo...   
4  https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-original-paleteria...   

                               text  
0                       Milk & Wood  
0           Dzui’s Cakes & Desserts  
0   Recess Italian Ice and Desserts  
0                           ICICLES  
0                  Sweet Rendezvous  
0     Passion-T Snacks and Desserts  
0  Vampire Penguin featuring Jastea  
0           Sweet Gelato Tea Lounge  
0                       Matcha Love  
0               Anton SV Pâtisserie  
1                              Oooh  
1                            Hannah  
1                          Chocatoo  
1                    Nox Cookie Bar  
1                Sweet Fix Creamery  
1                      My Milkshake  
1                       Matcha Love  
1                      Banana Crêpe  
1      Marco Polo Italian Ice Cream  
1       BlackBall Desserts San Jose  
2               Anton SV Pâtisserie  
2                   Soyful Desserts  
2                     Cocola Bakery  
2        Charlie’s Cheesecake Works  
2                        JT Express  
2                    Nox Cookie Bar  
2               Shuei-Do Manju Shop  
2                  Churros El Guero  
2               Sno-Crave Tea House  
2                          J.Sweets  
3                          Treatbot  
3                             CREAM  
3                      My Milkshake  
3                    Peters’ Bakery  
3              The Charming Kitchen  
3                Sweet Fix Creamery  
3                  California Mochi  
3                         Raw Sugar  
3                    Chola Desserts  
3             San Jose Tofu Company  
4                  The Sweet Corner  
4      Marco Polo Italian Ice Cream  
4                        Honeyberry  
4                            My Chè  
4                      Cre’Me Paris  
4                         Snowflake  
4              Willow Glen Creamery  
4                      Van’s Bakery  
4                    Happiness Cafe  
4   La Original Paleteria Y Neveria
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

````
df=pd.read_json('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rfmcnally/0a5a16e09374da7dd478ffbe6ba52503/raw/095e75121f31a8b7dc88aa89dbd637a944ce264a/ndjson-sample.json',lines=True)

#convert result column
df1=df.join(df['result'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(['result'],axis=1)

#convert pageData and rename. Because we have already timestamp col.
df1=df1.join(df1['pageData'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={'timestamp':'pageData_timestamp'})).drop(['pageData'],axis=1)

#convert extractorData and rename.
df1=df1.join(df1['extractorData'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={'url':'extractorData_url'})).drop(['extractorData'],axis=1).explode('data')

#explode extractorData['data']
df1=df1.join(df1['data'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(['data'],axis=1).explode('group')
df1=df1.join(df1['group'].apply(pd.Series)).explode('Business').drop(['group'],axis=1)

#finally convert our last dict type column (Business) and drop duplicates.
df1=df1.join(df1['Business'].apply(pd.Series)).drop(['Business'],axis=1).drop_duplicates()

print(df1)
'''
    url timestamp   sequenceNumber  statusCode  pageData_timestamp  extractorData_url   href    text
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/milk-and-wood-san-jose?osq=Desserts    Milk & Wood
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/dzuis-cakes-and-desserts-san-jose?osq=Desserts Dzui’s Cakes & Desserts
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/recess-italian-ice-and-desserts-san-jose?osq=Desserts  Recess Italian Ice and Desserts
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/icicles-san-jose-7?osq=Desserts    ICICLES
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/sweet-rendezvous-san-jose?osq=Desserts Sweet Rendezvous
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/passion-t-snacks-and-desserts-san-jose?osq=Desserts    Passion-T Snacks and Desserts
0   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    1513286383006   0   200 1513286383006   https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Desserts&find_loc=San+Jose,+CA&start=0    https://www.yelp.com/biz/vampire-penguin-featuring-jastea-san-jose?osq=Desserts Vampire Penguin featuring Jastea
..........

'''
```
````

Comment: I have it like this

Comment: so what do you need?

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunatly it came out in a vertical format. any ideas?

Comment: I checked but I still don't understand your problem. Did you try my solution? it was working very well. Can you explain the data in detail so that I can understand it better? or can you attach a sample of the expected output to the question?